# Error installing Microsoft ODBC 17 driver

Tags: drivers, server, microsoft, mssql

I'm trying to install the Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 in Ubuntu 20.04 following the instructions from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=alpine18-install%2Cubuntu17-install%2Cdebian8-install%2Credhat7-13-install%2Crhel7-offline).

However, when I type

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```

I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
msodbcsql17 is already the newest version (17.10.2.1-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up msodbcsql17 (17.10.2.1-1) ...
odbcinst: symbol lookup error: odbcinst: undefined symbol: iniOpen
dpkg: error processing package msodbcsql17 (--configure):
 installed msodbcsql17 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 msodbcsql17
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`odbcinst` seems to be correctly installed:

```
odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.11
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/atorres/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

I tried purging and reinstalling `unixodbc` and `odbcinst` but it did not work. I've also had no luck with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. Any idea what may be wrong with my system?

Comment: Its 20.04, I made a typo. It should be correct now

Comment: if the anwser does not fix it please edit into the q how far you get and I will either update or remove it :)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you forgot part of the instal. `odbcinst -i` will show the same error (so it is not related to apt but the execution of the setup after installing).

You need one of more of these:

```
sudo apt install odbcinst libsqliteodbc, msodbcsql17, odbc-postgresql, tdsodbc mysql-connector-odbc
```

If you need to reset odbcinst, before installing it again, remove

```
/usr/bin/odbcinst 
/etc/odbcinst.ini 
/usr/share/man/man1/odbcinst.1.gz
```

Comment: I will try that and report back, although the official Microsoft instructions do not mention anything about this. I assumed apt should handle the dependencies automatically.